# How to replace all characters but for the first and last two with gsub Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

Given any email address I would like to leave only the first and last two characters and input 4 asterisks to the left and right of @ character.

The best way to explain are examples:

`lorem.ipsum@gmail.com` changed to `lo****@****om` 
`foo@foo.de` changed `fo****@****de`

How to do it with gsub?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://ideone.com/yquKpO) might help.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you want to mask with a fixed number of `*` symbols, you may yse

```
'lorem.ipsum@gmail.com'.sub(/\A(..).*@.*(..)\z/, '\1****@****\2')
# => lo****@****om
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/pK26lZ).

Here,

- `\A`  - start of string anchor
- `(..)` - Group 1: first 2 chars
- `.*@.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the last `@` followed with another set of 0+ chars other than line break ones
- `(..)`  - Group 2: last 2 chars
- `\z` - end of string.

The `\1` in the replacment string refers to the value kept in Group 1, and `\2` references the value in Group 2.

**If you want to mask existing chars while keeping their number**, you might consider an approach to capture the parts of the string you need to keep or process, and manipulate the captures inside a `sub` block:

```
'lorem.ipsum@gmail.com'.sub(/\A(..)(.*)@(.*)(..)\z/) { 
    $1 + "*"*$2.length + "@" + "*"*$3.length + $4
}
# => lo*********@*******om
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/yquKpO)

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `(..)` - Group 1 capturing any 2 chars
- `(.*)` - Group 2 capturing any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last....
- `@`  - `@` char
- `(.*)` - Group 3 capturing any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the
- `(..)` - Group 4: last two chars
- `\z` - end of string.

Note that inside the block, `$1` contains Group 1 value, `$2` holds Group 2 value, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gsub` with look-ahead and look-behind regex patterns:

```
 'lorem.ipsum@gmail.com'.gsub(/(?<=.{2}).*@.*(?=\S{2})/, '****@****')
=> "lo****@****om"
```

Using plain ruby:

```
str.first(2) + '****@****' + str.last(2)
=> "lo****@****om"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which doesn't fully solve your problem but it's pretty flexible and I think it's worth it to share it for anyone else looking for similar solutions.

```
module CoreExtensions
  module String
    module MaskChars
      def mask_chars(except_first_n: 1, except_last_n: 2, mask_with: '*')
        if except_first_n.zero? && except_last_n.zero?
          raise ArgumentError, "except_first_n and except_last_n can't both be zero"
        end

        if length < (except_first_n + except_last_n)
          raise ArgumentError, "String '#{self}' must be at least #{except_first_n}"\
            " (except_first_n) #{except_last_n} (except_last_n) ="\
            " #{except_first_n + except_last_n} characters long"
        end

        sub(
          /\A(.{#{except_first_n}})(.*)(.{#{except_last_n}})\z/,
          '\1' + (mask_with * (length - (except_first_n + except_last_n))) + '\3'
        )
      end
    end    
  end
end
```

Let me explain the regex in `/\A(.{#{except_first_n}})(.*)(.{#{except_last_n}})\z/`

- `\A` - start of string
- `(.#{except_first_n})` or `(.{1})` Group 1: first `n` chars. Default value of `except_first_n` is `1`
- `(.*)` Group 2 capturing any 0+ chars as many as possible before the last `n` characters
- `(.#{except_last_n})` or `(.{2})` Group 3: last `n` chars. Default value of `except_last_n` is `2`
- `\z` - end of string

Let me explain what's happening in `'\1' + (mask_with * (length - (except_first_n + except_last_n))) + '\3'`

We are substituting the string with group 1 (`\1`) at the start, it'll contain characters equalling `except_first_n` argument's value. We are not gonna use group 2, we need to replace group 2 with the character from `mask_with` argument, to calculate the amount of times we need to add `mask_with` character, we use this formula `length - (except_first_n + except_last_n)` (total length of the string minus the sum value of `except_first_n` and `except_last_n`. This will ensure that we have the exact number of `mask_with` characters between the `except_first_n` and the `except_last_n` characters).

Then I created an initializer file config/initializers/core_extensions.rb with this line:
`String.include CoreExtensions::String::MaskChars`

It will add `mask_chars` as an instance method to the String class available to all strings.

It should work like this:

```
account = "123456789101112"
=> "123456789101112"
account.mask_chars
=> "1************12"
account.mask_chars(except_first_n: 3, except_last_n: 4, mask_with: '#')
=> "123########1112"
```

I think this is a pretty useful method which can be useful in many scenarios and very flexible too.